# Pull request at GitHub results in Compare changes page - how to proceed?

Tags: github, pull-request

I wanted to fix some typos in a Microsoft documentation repo.  I clicked on its ***New pull request*** button.  That resulted in the following page being displayed:

[image]

As you can see, the green ***Create pull request*** button is disabled.  How do I proceed from here?  In other repos (such as for Amazon documentation), the process works differently, and I am able to directly create a pull request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The common scenario of making such PRs looks like the following:

1. fork the repository http://prntscr.com/m7yhq0
2. make a new branch there with name like **fix/several-typos** http://prntscr.com/m7ytis
3. change a file and commit your changes to the branch (there should not be any difficulties)
4. go to the original repository, click **New pull request** and choose **compare across forks** http://prntscr.com/m7yih0
5. select necessary branches for PR and then the button **Create pull request** will be enabled.
6. Review your changes displayed below and click **Create pull request**

Hope that will help.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough!  I followed your instructions, and everything worked out like a charm.  The only difference was in step #4, where GitHub showed me the name of the new branch, making it even easier.  Here's what I mean: http://prntscr.com/m7znk5

Comment: Also, I am happy to be the person to accept your first answer on SO! :)

Comment: @sabuncu I'm glad I was able to help! And yeah, it was my first answer here. :)